# Совершенная раскраска графа

Tags: c++, алгоритм, графы

Здравствуйте, мне необходимо сделать совершенную раскраску графа.
"Раскраска вершин графа G называется совершенной, если для любых
двух вершин одного цвета цветовые составы их окружения совпадают.
В частности, это означает, что все соцветные вершины в G имеют одинаковую степень."
Мне необходимо раскрасить кубический (из вершины исходит 3 ребра) транзитивный граф в **2 цвета**
(белый и черный). По имеющийся матрице параметров A:

```
A = {{1,2},{2,1}}.
A[i] - это цвет нашей обрабатываемой вершины (0-белый, 1-черный).
A[i][0] - это столько вершин белого цвета соседствует с вершиной i-цвета.
A[i][1] - это столько вершин черного цвета соседствует с вершиной i-цвета.
```

Я сделал набросок кода:

```
void Graph::color() {
    //Инициализация?
    color_v[0] = 2;
    int m, p; //Белые и черные
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 * n; i++) {
        m = p = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 2 * n; j++) {
            if (matrix[i][j]) {
                if (color_v[j] == 1) m++;
                else if (color_v[j] == 2) p++;
                else {
                    if ((m < A[color_v[i]-1][0])) {
                        m++;
                        color_v[j] = 1;
                    }
                    else if ((p < A[color_v[i]-1][1])) {
                        p++;
                        color_v[j] = 2;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В массиве `color_v` у нас хранится цвет i вершины (0 - еще не окрашена, 1-белый, 2 - черный). То есть я просто перебираю вершины и крашу так, чтобы для каждой вершины условие в матрице совпадало, но мне кажется как-то не так сделал (не по уму). В интернете алгоритма не нашел. Данные у меня в виде матрицы смежности.

Comment: На худой конец перебор 2^8 = 256 вариантов не так уж и много. Могу сразу сказать - когда все вершины одного цвета, это идеальная раскраска :)

Comment: Как вам такая идея?. Пусть есть множество обработанных вершин. И вот, взять например i = 0 вершину, закрасить её в белый цвет, перекрасить по матрице параметров А смежные вершины. Добавить нашу вершину в множество обработанных, и обрабатывать до тех пор, пока есть множество необработанных.

Comment: Не ясно. В чем роль матрицы `A`? Почему вы называете ее "имеющейся"?

Comment: http://math.nsc.ru/publishing/DAOR/content/2011/02/03.pdf
Там всего 6 матриц допустимых матриц.